# Get reserved file names in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

It's known, you can't create a file with name `con` (`con.txt` for example) in Windows.
So, in my application user can input a custom file name (not via SaveFileDialog, just textbox to input name, not full path), and I want to show an error message, when user inputs invalid file name.
Is there a way to get full list of reserved Windows file names (`con`, `prn`, `lpt` and so on)?

Comment: Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There's no runtime API you could use - not in WinAPI, not in .NET. Which is a shame, because the file name (and path) limitations are platform-specific. Your only option is to try to create the file - but even that isn't entirely foolproof.

Comment: Usually, it's best to just let the user decide what he/she wants to name the file, then just go ahead and try to create it and let the Win32 API's tell you if you succeeded or not and then use the return value to get information on why it failed.

Comment: Furthermore, people might run your program on some future version of Windows (or Mono on Linux), where the filenames are acceptable. Just handle the exception if you get one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file:

CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.

Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

As per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note the list exists for extremely legacy reasons going back to DOS 1 and CPM, and will surely never be extended, so it is OK to hard-code the list. Note also the list is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [Reserved file names](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reserved-filenames)

> Reserved filenames in Windows operating systems
>
> aux
>   con
>   clock$
>   nul
>   prn
>   com1
>   com2
>   com3
>   com4
>   com5
>   com6
>   com7
>   com8
>   com9
>   lpt1
>   lpt2
>   lpt3
>   lpt4
>   lpt5
>   lpt6
>   lpt7
>   lpt8
>   lpt9

Comment: yes, I can hardcode them, i tried to find some "system" method to check file name

Comment: Seems windows forbid the file names whose resembles device names, but I didn't find any other reference to a predefined list

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GetFileType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletype) and disallow files of `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` in your application. That also works for reserved names like `con.txt` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, GetFileType is unsafe in this case:
https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO32-C.+Do+not+perform+operations+on+devices+that+are+only+appropriate+for+files#FIO32C.Donotperformoperationsondevicesthatareonlyappropriateforfiles-NoncompliantCodeExample(Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create that file in a %temp% folder. If you succeed, than, the name is valid. If you fail, you can show the user your message.

Also, I would check for already existing file with that name before creating.

After all, don't forget to delete it.

Comment: the file is created deffered, so i can't say is file created successfully just after user presss OK

Comment: @Backs You can say file is created successfully just when you have created it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

Though you should use your code under try catch block and catch the exception `system.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the file name to [`GetFullPathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamew). If the result starts with `\\.\`, it is a device name. [Java uses this method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/293fb46f7cd28f2a08055e3eb8ec9459d64e9688/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/WinNTFileSystem_md.c#L391-L397).

This method works only with NT-based Windows. If you still support Win9x, you will have to invoke a 16-bit DOS program to traverse the DOS device chain.