# Excel VBA code won't open a file named "CON.txt"

Tags: vba, windows, excel, filenames

I'm processing a large text file with pipe-delimited data in it where each line starts with a text "record type" field--e.g., "APP", "ATT", "CON", "A", "T"...  I need to split the file into a series of files with specific record types, so "APP.txt" has all the APP record types, etc.

What I'm doing is reading a line from the source file, grabbing the first field, checking if the token is in a collection and then, if the token is in the collection, opening that file and writing to it, or if the token is not in the collection, creating a new file, writing to it, and adding the token to the collection.  My program works fine, except when creating the "CON.txt" file:

- If I delete all the "CON" record types out of the source file, it works fine.
- If a "CON" record appears on line 2, it bombs out on line 2 creating the file.
- If a "CON" record appear on line 50, it bombs out on line 50.
- If I add a `p` in front of each token so the `CON` tokens are now `pCON` tokens, everything works fine.

I'm mystified.  Any idea why one specific file name would give this program conniptions?  The code that actually opens the file (which throws the 75 run-time error) is:

```
Open sTgtDir & sToken & ".txt" For Append As #iFileNo
```

Where `sTgtDir` is a path ending with "\" that works in all the other cases, `sToken` is the record type token, and `iFileNo` is an integer based on the count of items in the Token collection.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers, and about what to do when someone comments on, or answers, a question.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51447729/edit) to include more information if anyone asks, although I doubt anyone will.

Comment: You should read  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file before attempting to create any files on the Windows OS.

Comment: For future reference, see [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32561117/62576). MS operating systems reserve the filenames CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9, with or without an extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOS and Windows platforms [won't open a disk file named CON (with any extension)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073), because that is a special name referring to the "CONsole" (the screen).  Sorry - you're out of luck!  You'll simply have to use different token names (assuming you don't have the option of changing operating system).  For example, before the `Open` line you could add:

```
If UCase(sToken) = "CON" then sToken = "pCON"
```